# Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 image name in Autounattend.xml

Tags: windows

I tried to build a new image of Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 with my old Autounattend.xml that worked with Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1703 (Updated July 2017), but the install stops at the select version screen.

Anyone that knows the new image name, or knows how I can find it?

Here is my current ImageInstall element:

```
<ImageInstall>
    <OSImage>
        <InstallFrom>
            <MetaData wcm:action="add">
                <Key>/IMAGE/NAME </Key>
                <Value>Windows 10 Enterprise</Value>
            </MetaData>
        </InstallFrom>
        <InstallTo>
            <DiskID>0</DiskID>
            <!-- PartitionID: UEFI = 4, Non UEFI = 2-->
            <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
        </InstallTo>
    </OSImage>
</ImageInstall>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it using brute force. It was not "Windows 10", not "Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC", but "Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the image description instead of name.

```
                        <Key>/IMAGE/DESCRIPTION</Key>
                        <Value>Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC</Value>
```

Comment: How does this solution improve on the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but this will be useful for future image releases. Image name or index can vary among ISO, even a custom one. One way to check the actual names is:

1. Start an elevated Powershell session.
2. Mount ISO file (or GUI: Double click from File Explorer):

   ```
   Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "<path to ISO.iso>"
   ```
3. Check the drive letter recently mounted (i.e.`G:`)

   ```
   Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath G:\sources\install.wim | Format-Table
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   PS ADMIN [C:\Users\gbarcelo] > Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath I:\sources\install.wim | Format-Table

   RunspaceId                           ImagePath              ImageName                    ImageIndex ImageDescription
   ----------                           ---------              ---------                    ---------- ----------------
   6cff0ef4-21d0-49d3-959a-c9952c63cdd3 I:\sources\install.wim Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC            1 Windows 10 Enterpr…
   6cff0ef4-21d0-49d3-959a-c9952c63cdd3 I:\sources\install.wim Windows 10 Enterprise N LTSC          2 Windows 10 Enterpr…
   ```